# Giving id to the element repeated

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using ng-repeat in angularJS to create elements. I want to apply id to the element which is repeated, in this case `li`

HTML Code:

```
<li id="{{item}}" ng-repeat="item in itmes"></li>
```

All the syntax and declaration is perfect in my code. However, the above code does not work. I want below output to be generated. If `items = ['one', 'two', 'three']`

```
<li id="one" ng-repeat="item in items">...</li>
<li id="two" ng-repeat="item in items">...</li>
<li id="three" ng-repeat="item in items">...</li>
```

Is it possible using angularJS?

Comment: It should work, what issue are you facing.

Comment: Try to add something inside `li`. `<li id="{{item}}" ng-repeat="item in itmes">{{item}}</li>` and change `itMEs` to `itEMs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<li ng-attr-id="{{item}}" ng-repeat="item in itmes"></li>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-attr-id="{{item}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
// Code goes here
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',
      function ($scope) {
          $scope.items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
      }
    ]);

})();

and output
```

[image]

**and plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/M6BDcJ2csgBR4C9TNdbz?p=preview

Comment: Can you explain why that should be done or offer some relevant material?

Answer (score 2):

you have typo in items.

```
<li id="{{item}}" ng-repeat="item in itmes"></li>

 item in `itmes`
```

change this to items and try.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q7g8kwqt/)